Bulletized lists in APA paper
I am looking at the APA7 guidebook, and having issues understanding bullets.  The guidance refers to the needs of the document to determine this.  However, I need to format this for APA requirements for my university.
Are bullets doublespaced themselves?  and my second question, what if an individual bullet is multi-lined (ie. longer than one line and word wraps). Is the individual bullet single-spaced? or is everything doublespaced?
Thanks

Does this not help: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/lists/bulleted

Thank you no, it doesn't unfortunately.  I'm not seeing where it says in guidance that bullets and the list are either way.  Right now, I'm counting pixels and guessing.

Please see the examples--bullets are double spaced, but if a bullet goes into multiple lines, those are single spaced.
